# MATLAB: Scatter Plot with matrix data

Tags: excel, matlab, matrix, plot, scatter

I am trying to perform the scatter plot of `X` and `Y` matrices, each of size `54x365`, with the following code on MATLAB. The data was extracted from excel.

```
clc
clear
A = xlsread('Test_data.xlsx', 'Sheet 1', 'F3:NF56');
B = xlsread('Test_data.xlsx', 'Sheet 2', 'F3:NF56');
scatter (A,B)
```

Although they are of similar size, MATLAB produces the following statement:

```
Error using scatter (line 44)
X and Y must be vectors of the same length.

Error in Untitled2 (line 11)
scatter(A,B)
```

Note the following:

```
A = [ A, B, C, D, E ;
      F, G, H, I, J ]

B = [ a, b, c, d, e ;
      f, g, h, i, j ]
```

The variables `(A,a)`, `(B,b)` and so on are plotted so as to produce a scatter plot.

I need help to perform the scatter plot. Thank you.

Comment: What are currently the sizes/dimension of matrices/vectors `A` and `B` shown in the MATLAB workspace panel to the right?

Comment: Both are 54x365 double.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reshaping the arrays as row vectors may allow the `scatter()` function to plot the data. Here the arrays are reshaped to have dimensions that are 1 by `Number_Of_Values` in each array.

```
%Generating random test data%
A = rand(54,365);
B = rand(54,365);

%Reshaping to allow plotting%
Number_Of_Values = numel(A);
A = reshape(A,[1 Number_Of_Values]);
B = reshape(B,[1 Number_Of_Values]);

scatter(A,B);
```

**Ran using MATLAB R2019b**

Comment: No problem, happy to help. :)